# How to add another page to Silverstripe CMS admin

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

I have been looking at [this tutorial](http://www.silverstriperesources.com/articles/creating-a-totally-custom-page-in-the-admin-area/) on adding a simple page to the admin area of Silverstripe (3.0.5) but get segmentation fault errors in the apache log.

I think that the issue is the "index" method in "customHelp.php" - when I rename "index" to something else, I get no crashes and an entry in the admin menu, but obviously nothing is displayed when I click on it.

Here is the contents of my "customHelp.php" - can somebody please point me in the right direction?

```
<?php

class customHelp extends LeftAndMain { 

    static $url_segment = "customHelp"; 
    static $menu_title = "Site Help";     
    static $allowed_actions = array ('customHelp'); 

    public function index() { 
        return $this->renderWith('customHelp'); 
    }     

    public function init() { 
        parent::init(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the issue is with your index method? Can you be more specific about the error? What do you have in your customHelp.ss file?

Comment: I just get "No data received - server sent no data" in my web page (with the URL http://mysite.local/admin/customHelp/ ). If I rename index() to xindex() for example, the admin site loads fine, presumably because that method isn't being called. My "customHelp.ss" is the same as on the tutorial page (stored in /customHelp/templates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the tutorial is not correct or outdated.

I tried it here and got the error:

```
Declaration of customHelp::index() should be compatible with that of LeftAndMain::index()
```

So making it compatible for overiding with:

```
public function index($request) { 
    return $this->renderWith('customHelp'); 
}
```

made it work here.

Comment: Thanks - I've got a bit further now (not sure why I didn't see that same error message) but now once I've clicked on the "site help" menu item, the right-hand side of the page seems to stick. Clicking on any of the other menu items doesn't get rid of the "custom html content" text. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: i can confirm this strange behaviour, but i cant tell why this happens. the content get loaded but not displayed. Maybe you should use a LeftAndMainExtension instead of extending. http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/howto/extend-cms-interface

Comment: Thanks - I'll try that instead. Don't think I picked the best tutorial to follow ;) Your solution fixed the original issue anyway so thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Might not be related but you should use the right naming convention in the class names even the guide suggests otherwise:

Classes should start with an uppercase letter http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/trunk/misc/coding-conventions and the filenames should follow this.

You can run in to issues when running on a server that serves the files as case sensitive.

EDIT:

just hit me that the index issue could be caused by unlfushed template cache: run ?flush=all on the site.

Comment: Thanks - I'm repeatedly running ?flush=all on my site whenever I make any changes. Do you think renaming the class name will help? I'm just following that tutorial page and that's how the class is named there...